# how can I match Laravel .env with XAMPP configuration settings?

Tags: mysql, laravel, web, xampp, backend

I changed XAMPP configuration ports and localhost, when I ran old project it doesn't work so I need anyone to help me to match the .env with XAMPP configuration

the XAMPP window

[image: XAMPP Window]

Apache Service Window

[image: Apache]

MySQL Service Window

[image: MySQL]

the .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:kuAaczKFkzJWGNlZzrPpsBsmv+NNMCMPVwTsNYsbZyc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mobitech
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: Set your APP_URL and DB_PORT accordingly, not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

If you want work Laravel with XAMPP, you need to check 2 things.

1- First your root folder must be laravel's public folder. So to do that click the Apache Config button and select the Apache httpd.conf option. Then find the `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"` and change with `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public"`

2- Laravel's database options are in the .env file. XAMPP uses MySQL and its port is 3306. In the .env file `DB_PORT` key default value is also 3306. You you need to change port as your option (3308).

So when you enter the localhost or 127.0.0.1 probably it will work. But you had changed the http port as 1234, so you must enter https://localhost:1234 as an address.